# Swing apllication with embedded JavaFX WebView won't play html5 video only sound

Tags: macos, swing, webview, javafx, html5-video

In my Swing application I needed support for rendering html. So I embedded a JavaFX WebView in my Swing application. Now on some html pages I use the new html5 -Tag to play a video. This works perfectly on Windows and Linux. But on MacOS I only hear the sound and see a black video frame and the time track in the bottom.

Here is an SSCCE I got from [github](https://gist.github.com/anjackson/1640654). I just changed the url to one that contains a html5 video-tag example. Would be great, if you MacOS users could try it and tell me if the same happens on you computer. And of course any idea to fix this is appreciated.

SSCCE:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl;

/**
 * SwingFXWebView
 */
public class JavaFXTest extends JPanel
{
    private Stage     stage;
    private WebView   browser;
    private JFXPanel  jfxPanel;
    private JButton   swingButton;
    private WebEngine webEngine;
    private Object    geo;

    public JavaFXTest()
    {
        this.initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        // Run this later:
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JavaFXTest());
                frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
        this.jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        this.createScene();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(this.jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.swingButton = new JButton();
        this.swingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
            {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        JavaFXTest.this.webEngine.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        this.swingButton.setText("Reload");
        this.add(this.swingButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    /**
     * createScene Note: Key is that Scene needs to be created and run on
     * "FX user thread" NOT on the AWT-EventQueue Thread
     */
    private void createScene()
    {
        PlatformImpl.startup(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JavaFXTest.this.stage = new Stage();
                JavaFXTest.this.stage.setTitle("Hello Java FX");
                JavaFXTest.this.stage.setResizable(true);
                final Group root = new Group();
                final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 80, 20);
                JavaFXTest.this.stage.setScene(scene);
                // Set up the embedded browser:
                JavaFXTest.this.browser = new WebView();
                JavaFXTest.this.webEngine = JavaFXTest.this.browser.getEngine();
                JavaFXTest.this.webEngine.load("http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html");
                final ObservableList<Node> children = root.getChildren();
                children.add(JavaFXTest.this.browser);
                JavaFXTest.this.jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... see a black rect and hear nothing on windows. Even without mixing swing/fx. For plain fx, I just changed the [tutorial example 3](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) to your test url

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for the info. I wonder why javaFX behaves so differently, though. Can you tell me which javafx version you are running? For example mp4 H.264 is only supported from JavaFX 2.1 on. I have installed JavaFX 2.2

Comment: tested with the fx that comes with jdk7u45 (or maybe u21 updated a couple of days ago and don't recall when exactly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a semi-answer, which might help:
The [oracle website](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml) states:"At this time, Online Installation and Java Update features are not available for 64-bit architectures"

For me this caused lots of problems, because Java seems up to date, but actually isn't. On some machines I could solve the actual issue by just manually updating the Java 64bit VM. On Mac however, the video still isn't playing, only sound.

The 64bit/32bit issue gets even worse, since a double click on a jar might start it in the 64bit JVM, but via console it is started in 32bit JVM. So if you do a "java -version" in console, the output might be "1.7.0 u45 32-bit", but as soon as you start the jar via double click it is started in an outdated 64bit JVM.

So if you ever run in an JavaFX issue (especially with UnsatisfiedLinkError) and you have a 64bit computer, just install the latest 64bit java and hope that it solves the problem.